# screen resolution stuck under 1366x768

Tags: ati, resolution, screen

I want my old machine (Athlon XP, Radeon9200, Ubuntu 11 on a 19" Mitsubishi Diamondtron) to display a screen resolution of at least 1600x1200 @ 75hz. The monitor's control panel gives no option and xrandr / flgrx commands does nothing.

Anyone who knows a working command line wins one free internet, otherwise I'll just roll back to XP pro. Yes I know ATI has NO drivers... but it's a good machine, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

ATI has Catalyst drivers. I had them installed before.

From the Dash, open the **Additional Hardware** software. Your graphics card (and maybe other hardware) will be automatically detected and proprietary drivers for it will be displayed.

Go ahead and install.